# How to cut a String character with foreach loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, stringtokenizer

I have an `ArrayList[ 1 2 3, 2 6 7, 3 4 8]`, its characters are ordered alphabetically.

I want to : for each element of the list : 1 2 3 for example, that i can all the sub-elements which means : 1 2, 1 3, 2 3

an this for each size of list for example `ArrayList[ 1 2 3 4 , 2 6 7 8]` , i must have in return, for 1 2 3 4 , all of its sub-elements : 1 2 3, 1 2 4 ,1 3 4, 2 3 4

i wrote a code that do that, it seems like this :

```
        for (int t = 0; t < tempCandidates.size(); t++) {

            st3 = new StringTokenizer(tempCandidates.get(t));

            str3 = null;

            //To have some memory a do a self clear for those arrayLists
            tempCandidates2.clear();
            tempCandidates3.clear();
            Vec_L1.clear();

            do {

                str3 = st3.nextToken();
                tempCandidates2.add(str3); 

            } while (st3.hasMoreTokens());

            for (int x = tempCandidates2.size(), w1 = x - 1; w1 >= 0; w1--) {
                //remove1 is a function that remove element from a list from a specific index
                Vec_L1 = remove1(tempCandidates2, w1);

                str4 = new String();

                for (int w = 0; w < Vec_L1.size(); w++) {

                    st4 = new StringTokenizer(Vec_L1.get(w));
                    str4 = str4 + " " + st4.nextToken();

                }

                tempCandidates3.add((str4).trim()); 

            }
            //other code for other stuff
    }
```

The idea is to retrive the last element of each element of the list tempCandidates (the list that contains [1 2 3, 2 3 4 ...], and use StringTokenizer each time to have a string like this 1 2, 1 3 ...

So my question, is there any one to help to optimize this code, for doing it fatestly, because i do this treatement for a millio of elements, so i must write the fatest code possible.

Or can we do with Split method instead of StringTokenIzer because in Oracle docs they said that we must split.

other question please, can anyone tell if Threads can do it better here.

I used this code `here is some that i wrote it with String class, using substring`
code`
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ConcurrentStringTokenIzer {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> listTemp1 = new ArrayList<>();

    //Generate Elements of the list
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add(Integer.toString(i) + " " + Integer.toString(i + 1) + " "
                + Integer.toString(i + 2) + " "
                        + Integer.toString(i + 3));
    }

    for (String list1 : list) {

        String d = new String();


        for (int i = 0; i<h; i++) {

            for (int j = list1.length(); j >0; j=j-2) {

                if(j == list1.length()){
                    d = list1.substring(i,j-2).trim();
                    if(d.length()<list1.length()-2)
                        break;
                }
                else{
                    d = list1.substring(i,j-1)+list1.substring(j+1,list1.length()).trim();
                }


            }


        }

    }

}
```

}

the problem with that is we use a character that has more than an element like 10 11 12, it blocks.

can any one help me, so to work with substring indexes or other manner to work with withspaces.

thank you`
Thank you very much.

Comment: Edit your question instead of commenting on it with more info. Also, post code that we can run by copy-pasting it into our IDE.

Comment: "*i must write the fatest code possible.*" Probably not what you want.

Comment: i can't put the hole of the code.

Comment: Sounds like a good use-case for [Java 8's parallel streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html). Map-reduce, maybe?

Comment: yes i'm writing a code for Apriori algorithm